How to stop Audacity from stealing focus?
Audacity steals focus when

Importing multiple files (each time a file is imported, Audacity steals focus)
Processing multiple files (for example, when I apply tempo change to multiple files, each time the change is applied to a new file, Audacity steals focus)
Exporting multiple files (each time a file is exported, Audacity steals focus)

Is there any way to stop such behavior? (Instead of stealing focus, how can I get Audacity to just silently work in the background?)
(I'm using Audacity 3.6.4 and Windows 11 Home 10.0.22631 Build 22631.)

Does this happen even when Audacity is minimized? Or, if running a batch process from command line, when started minimized  by a shortcut (Properties: Run: Minimized)?

@DrMoishePippik: When performing any of the above tasks, the whole Audacity window is frozen and I'm not allowed to minimize it. //  I'm not running from command line.

Have you tried using Windows hotkeys: Win+ ↓ (minimize current window), Win+Esc (send to back), Win+M (minimize all, then bring back other app windows manually), or Alt+Tab (needs to be repeated after Audacity steals focus)?

@DrMoishePippik: Win+↓ doesn't work, Win+Esc stops the operation in Audacity, Win+M minimizes all windows except Audacity.

Sorry I was of no help.
